# Where do the debug results go in VSCODE?

Tags: remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a python code inside a docker environment, using a python interpreter defined in a conda environment.
I can succesfully "run Python file in terminal"
But when I try to debug (F5) nothing happens in the terminal, nor the variables are loaded in the debug panel.

Answer (score 0):

There are tabs in the same section where you opened your terminal. Check that out

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. I see no prompt in the debug console. The Debug Console is empty

Comment: Have you setup the debugging environment for your language? I guess its called "launch configurations" in VSCode